# Routing and namespaces in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

A part of a code of a Ruby on Rails application:

```
    #routes.rb
        namespace :admin do
              root :to => 'admin#index'
              resources :orders, :products
        end

  #controllers/admin/admin_contrller.rb
    class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
       def index

       end
    end
```

The `index` view is located in `views/admin/index.html.haml`. However, it doesn't find it (`http://localhost:3000/admin`, **missing template**). It only finds it if it's located in `views/admin/admin/index.html.haml`.

What do I did wrong? What should I do to make it to find the view in `views/admin/index.html.haml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created namespace :admin and put there root path and orders resource. Root path is pointed to `index` adction of `AdminController`. Having this configuration, rails will lookup for `index.html.haml` view under `views/admin/admin/index.html.haml` where first admin is namespace and second is controller's directory.

You did nothing wrong. It's just how rails work.

I would suggest, instead of trying to find the view in `views/admin/index.html.haml` to simply change `AdminController` name into `DashboardController` and creating `BaseController` as a base class for all controllers under `admin/` directory.

app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  #auth etc.
end
```

app/controllers/admin/dashboard_controller.rb

```
class Admin::DashboardController < Admin::BaseController

end
```

This way you'll easily add authentication, authorization, different layout etc. etc. and other stuff needed for admin controllers

But If you really want to sick with your solution, you can just simply do `render admin/index` in index action like this:

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render "admin/index"
  end
end
```

Comment: <<I would suggest, instead of trying to find the fiew in views/admin/index.html.haml>> Is there any way to set view path manually?

Comment: Just edited my answer and added alternative solution which would satisfy you ;)